# Save UITextField text from a custom View inside a UIAlert

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uitextfield, uialertview

```
UIAlertView *alert = ......
UIView *customView = ....
UITextField *textField = ......
textField.text = @"Enter Name";

[customView addSubview: textField];
[alert setValue: alertView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[alert show];

self.string = textField.text;
```

The string @"Enter Name" is saved into self.string instead of user input of the Text Field.
And I have three textFields so I can't use the username/pass of uialert

Comment: Try giving all the UITextFields a unique tag so you know which is which by asking viewWithTag:

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to show "Enter Name" in your UIAlertView?

To set the text field:

UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:INDEX-HERE];
textField.text = @"Enter Name"

To get the value of the text field:

In alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex, you can access the text boxes view alertView textFieldAtIndex:. The index starts at 0.

Comment: I would use that but I need three textFields and the max in an alert is 2, hence the custom view. I do not know how to pass the data in the textFields from the custom view in the alert message back to the view controller.

Comment: If you want to pass data back to the calling view, aka get the data from your custom view controller, you can create a delegate and make your calling view controller be a delegate for your alert view controller.